# Edit response for data from database laravel

Tags: laravel

I have an api which gives a response of data from database. I want to twig the response in order to meet my requirement.

The response is:

```
{
    "status_code": "200",
    "msg": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "objective_id": 1,
            "question": "What is this edited",
            "option_a": "a",
            "option_b": "b",
            "option_c": "c",
            "option_d": "d",
            "correct": "3",
            "created_at": "2022-08-26T05:35:32.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-08-26T05:35:32.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "objective_id": 1,
            "question": "how is this edited",
            "option_a": "e",
            "option_b": "f",
            "option_c": "g",
            "option_d": "h",
            "correct": "2",
            "created_at": "2022-08-26T05:35:32.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-08-26T05:35:32.000000Z"
        },
    ]
}
```

The response is obtained from:

```
$questions = OBQuestion::where('objective_id', $objectives)->get();

            return Response::json(array(
                'status_code' => '200',
                'msg' => $questions
             ), 200);
```

Now I want my response showing something like this:

```
{
    "status_code": "200",
    "msg": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "objective_id": 1,
            "question": "how is this edited",
            "options":[
                  "option_a": "e",
                  "option_b": "f",
                  "option_c": "g",
                  "option_d": "h",
            ],
            "correct": "2",
            "created_at": "2022-08-26T05:35:32.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-08-26T05:35:32.000000Z"
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can do this by creating a `foreach` for Iterating through the `$questions`  and then adding the data to the array as your arrangement needs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @rohit-bhati
Did it like this

```
foreach($questions as $q){
     $res[] = [
      'question'  => $q->question,
       'options'   => [
                        "$q->option_a",
                        "$q->option_b",
                        "$q->option_c",
                        "$q->option_d",
                    ],
                    "correctIndex"  => (int) $q->correct,
                ];
            }
            return Response::json(array(
                'status_code' => '200',
                'msg' => $res
             ), 200);
```